# MySQL ucfirst doesn't work

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `events` (
  `evt_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `evt_name` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ucfirst',
  `evt_description` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `evt_startdate` date NOT NULL,
  `evt_enddate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `evt_starttime` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `evt_endtime` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `evt_amtpersons` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sts_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `adr_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `evt_amtPersonsSubs` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `evt_photo` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sys-mut-dt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `sys-mut-user` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sys-mut-id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`evt_id`),
  KEY `sts_id` (`sts_id`),
  KEY `adr_id` (`adr_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;
```

But when I add in data into `evt_name` my first character is not capitalized. Any ideas?

Further information:
MySQL client version: 5.1.37

I want to do this in the database so that I don't have to do `ucfirst` with php always.

Comment: I'd always use 'formatting' functions in PHP. It would make life easier if you needed to reuse the data in a different application in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...what?

If I'm reading this right, it will just set the default value of `evt_name` to the string `ucfirst`. Try inserting a blank row and see if I'm reading that right.

If you're really against using `ucfirst` in PHP, you'll probably have to still call `ucfirst` every time in the query. Or you could only use `ucfirst` on display, and not in the database.

Comment: ok I thought i just could aragne it in the table itself without doing it in each query.

Answer (score 2):

`ucfirst` is a function...you defined it as Default-Value for the cell. Use it like this:

```
INSERT INTO events SET evt_name = UCFIRST($value)
```

Comment: `UCFIRST` is not a standard mysql function.

Comment: If you want to do this in a standard way, use:
```INSERT INTO `events` SET
`evt_name` = CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT('$value', 1)), LOWER(SUBSTRING('$value', 2)))```